# Best way to get Open Data Community to Engage (Attend/Volunteer) at The White House Open Data Summit?

Tags: uses-of-open-data

Wondering what are the best methods/approaches to informing the Open Data Community of the upcoming Open Data Innovation Summit at the White House.
Attendees and volunteers are needed, and anyone with interest in Open Data that will be in the DC metro area is invited.

More Information About the Event:
The White House Open Data Innovation Summit with Solutions Showcase is taking place onSeptember 28, 2016 at the Walter E. Washington Convention Center in DC, and we need your help to make this an even better event! We plan on selling out in the next few days, so now's your last chance to register

The Summit will highlight the Obama Administration’s work in opening U.S. government data and to discuss the path forward to continue this progress. This event will feature cutting-edge uses of government open data to promote government efficiency and effectiveness, drive innovation, economic opportunity, and improve the health and welfare of the American public. During this free and open Summit we will hear from people on the front lines who are championing data-driven innovations.

To attend as a general or half-day attendee, [register at this link.](https://www.eventbrite.com/e/the-white-house-open-data-innovation-summit-registration-27474029562)

Questions? More information on the Summit [can be found here](https://www.data.gov/event/white-house-open-data-innovation-summit/) or contact WHOpenData@gsa.gov.

Comment: love the effort and thought behind this, but this doesn't fit open data se's requirements for asking questions. you should post this in meta....or maybe even reword this as to how to get the word out to the open data community. actually i like that option.

Comment: i may actually register now. nicely done.

Comment: ...so i signed up but got wait listed....hint hint